# Mule transactions - reliability patterns - Mule in Action 2

Tags: mule

I am reading Mule in Action (which is excellent) and trying out listing 7.5 about reliability patterns with transactions but it doesn't work as I expected. 
The flow doesn't wait for the message to be placed on the queue and returns the http message straight away. Am I missing something? Should this not be wrapped in an async block?

```
<flow name="orderSubmission">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
          host="localhost" port="8081"
          path="order"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service
         serviceClass="com.prancingdonkey.service.OrderSubmissionService"/>
    <component
        class="com.prancingdonkey.service.OrderSubmissionServiceImpl"/>
    <async>
        <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="order.submit">
            <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN"/>
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
    </async>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you posted seems like Listing 7.4 of Mule in Action (2nd ed). And I agree, it is an excellent book.

From what I understand, what is happening here is that the async scope creates a copy of the message and continues processing. Since you reach the "end of the line" when you hit the async block, your flow enters the response phase while the message is being queued (not queued yet) in the JMS outbound endpoint.

The idea here is that you can send an HTTP response message before continuing your potentially long internal processing, thus freeing the client to perform more work while it is waiting for the processing to finish. The book mentioned Gregor Hohpe's Starbucks analogy which explained this very well for me. Perhaps you can have look at it again.

Your observations on how the flow describes its intended behaviour, despite not up to your expectation. If you are looking for a purely synchronous behaviour where we wait until the message is successfully put into the JMS queue, then you should remove the async scope.

Comment: Yes 7.4. The reason is because the preceding text says: 'If the JMS transaction that submits the message on the
queue succeeds, then a response containing the order ID is returned to the mobile
device.' which implies if the queuing fails then no id should be sent back. Also this isn't fully reliable as you cannot garauntee the message has been put on the queue. The async part should happen in the back end processing picking up from the queue.

Comment: I believe you are correct. If we look at Figure 7.5, we see that there is no async block around the JMS outbound endpoint.